# How to fetch git:// project instead of https:// Project:http://git.infradead.org/mtd-utils.git

Tags: git

I am trying to clone one project from http://git.infradead.org/mtd-utils.git

Which is either git or ssh based, by laptop is configured to download either http or https projects.

How to download git:// projects ??

URL to download above project:

git://git.infradead.org/mtd-utils.git

ssh://git.infradead.org/var/lib/git/mtd-utils.git

I tried to replace git:// with https:// no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `git clone git://git.infradead.org/mtd-utils.git` Work fine for me :)